# About Gaussian Random Vectors

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent $N(\mu, K)$ Gaussian random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If we denote by $i_1^*$ the coordinate at which $X_1$ has maximum value, I want to get a lower bound on the following probability 
$P( X_2(i_1^*)>X_1(i_1^*))$.

I think since $i_1^*$ is also a random variable, my approach is to first condition it on $X_1$ which fixes $i_1^*$. After that we can write

$P(X_2(i_1^*)>X_1(i_1^*)) \geq \mathbb{E}[P(X_2(i_1^*)>X_1(i_1^*)|X_1) ] \geq \mathbb{E}[P(X_2(i_1^*)>c, X_1(i_1^*)\leq c|X_1) ]$ for some $c >0$.

Is there a better way of going about doing this. I think that it should be bounded away from zero, and possibly the probability would be small if $n$ increases. Also, I don't think I have used the fact that the two have the same distribution anywhere. 
Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, $\mu$ is fixed for all components ? And $K \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}^n$ is the "variance" vector ? Also $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same $\mu$ and $K$ ?

Comment: Actually $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the mean vector, and $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is the covariance matrix, i.e. the $(i,j)$ element of $K$ is $\mathbb{E}[(X(i)-\mu(i))(X(j)-\mu(j))]$, and yes, $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution and are independent.